# Do new Air conditioning units require new pads?

Tags: hvac

Is a new pad required when an entire new central AC unit (inside, outside, ductwork, everything) is installed?  Does the outside unit require anything around it when it’s in the backyard?

Answer (score 1):

If the existing pad is large enough and in good shape it should be fine. The only time I put something around the condenser (outside unit) is if there are dogs, dogs love to pee on these and the urine destroys the fins fairly quickly reducing the efficiency and causing leaks in extreme cases.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.  That was exactly the issue.